# PHP read Hindi text file in unicode format

Tags: php

I am using this code for reading a file which contains Hindi alphabets.

```
<?php
$arrbyline=file('E:\HindiFile.txt');
foreach($arrbyline as $lines)
{
   echo $lines . "<BR>";
}
```

HindiFile.txt:

```
नमस्कार सज्जनों
```

But I am getting this:

```
ÿþ( . 8 M > 0 8 M ( K
```

Here, I am getting unknown characters. How can I get my Hindi chars?

Comment: Please post the file content or just 1 line as example. Also what exact error do you get?

Comment: is there a direct translation between Hindi and Latin? as in can you translate कार सज्जनों to a-z script?

Comment: Works fine for me! What output do you get now and what do you expect?

Comment: I am getting this ÿþ( . 8 M  > 0 8  M  ( K

Comment: @Rohan Please use the edit button of your question to show the current output and the expected one

Comment: are you sure you have installed a hindi font?

Comment: How do you run this file? What is the this script's current client current encoding set?

Comment: Ofcourse, i have Hindi fonts installed. I am running the file through my firefox browser.

Comment: How is the file encoded? UTF8, 16, 32? You need to send an according header to the browser.

Comment: Okay, it's FF. What is the page encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should save your file in `utf-8`. then
read your file like this:

```
if (file_exists($SourceDirectoryFile))
{
    $NameBook  = "HindiFile.txt";

    $contents = file_get_contents($NameBook);

    // browser should display UTF-8 characters
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    echo $contents . '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. As it stand there is no guarantee that the file is UTF8 encoded.

Comment: If it's hindi and saved properly, it should be utf-8.
BTW thanks for alert

Comment: No, it could also be UTF16 or any other crazy encoding. Please read this http://global.joelonsoftware.com/English/Articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: Getting the same ��( . 8 M  > 0 8  M  ( K

Comment: @Rohan what if you upload a file somewhere? It could be more productive since you're ignoring all questions about the actual file encoding.

Comment: The file was saved as Unicode encoded. Now i saved the file as utf-8 & the above code is working fine.

Comment: "The file was saved as Unicode encoded. Now i saved the file as utf-8" --- this phrase makes no sense. Unicode is a character set, utf-8 is encoding. A file cannot be "unicode encoded"

Comment: Can i use the result to change the file name with "नमस्कार.txt", since as for your answer, we have used **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');** to show in html content. Now i want to change the name of a file with **नमस्कार.txt**.

Comment: first of all you did not use utf-8. so the problem was from saving the file.
and BTW please confirm the answer. thanks

Comment: I am trying to save a file with that Hindi Text but not getting saved. Here Content-Type helps to display Hindi Text but cannot save file with that text. How can i do that ?